# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper is named OpenShiftBuildWrapper

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I am getting below error in Jenkins Pipeline Job:

```
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of class 
   jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildWrapper is named OpenShiftBuildWrapper
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.resolveClass(DescribableModel.java:549)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.coerce(DescribableModel.java:473)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.buildArguments(DescribableModel.java:409)

Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {delegate={$class=OpenShiftBuildWrapper, url=https://in-console.appcanvas.net:8443, credentialsId=jenkins-paas-token, installation=oc-latest, insecure=true}} for org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreWrapperStep
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.DescribableModel.instantiate(DescribableModel.java:334)
```

The step in Jenkinsfile which is causing issue is :

```
    stage('Deploy to Demo AppCanvas') {
      when {
        expression {
          env.BRANCH_NAME=='develop'
        }
      }
      steps{
        script{
         // withCredentials([string (credentialsId: 'jenkins-paas-token', variable: 'OPENSHIFT_AUTH_TOKEN')]) {
          if (env.BRANCH_NAME=='develop') {
            echo "Promoting application from " + properties.project_dev + " to " + properties.project_demo
            OPENSHIFT_CONSOLE_URL = 'https://in-console.appcanvas.net:8443'
          }
         
          
          AUTH_TOKEN_DEMO = 'jenkins-paas-token'
          
          if(env.BRANCH_NAME=='develop') {
            StageToDemoDeployToAppCanvas(properties.project_demo,properties.oc_app_name,properties.project_stage,IMAGE_TAG,OPENSHIFT_CONSOLE_URL,AUTH_TOKEN_DEMO)
          }
         // }
        }
      }
    }
```

Below is the part of code snippet from StgToDemoDeployToAppCanvas.groovy :

```
     def call(String project_demo, String oc_app_name, String project_stage, String IMAGE_TAG, String OPENSHIFT_CONSOLE_URL, String OPENSHIFT_AUTH_TOKEN){
  wrap([$class: 'OpenShiftBuildWrapper', url: OPENSHIFT_CONSOLE_URL, credentialsId: OPENSHIFT_AUTH_TOKEN, installation: 'oc-latest', insecure: true])
```